# What does "having a mid off" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

[image]I've seen a lot of people using "having mid off" on twitter and some other app, don't know what it's mean

Comment: I suspect it's recently coined slang - [Urban Dictionary: mid off](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Mid%20off)

Comment: @KillingTime now I get it, thanks

Comment: [Used to insult or degrade an opposing opinion,](https://wiki.celebrity.fm/have-a-mid-off-meaning-91535/) labeling it as average or poor quality. Examples: *We waited on that album for 6 months but it was **mid**! Get a **mid** mug for your Uncle Paul*. From which I conclude that this (previously unknown to me) usage doesn't necessarily include either the hyphen or the word ***off***. Plus I assume it's derived from the cricket fielding position, so it would probably never gain much currency (since the worlds *primary* Anglophones - Americans - don't do cricket anyway! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for the explanation.

Comment: It has been proposed that this question be closed on the ground that the OP hasn't done sufficient preliminary research. Given that the usage is so new, it is, however, not clear what research the OP could have done.

Comment: Agree with @jsw29. Research in this case would likely have come up with a different, clearly incorrect definition for the context (i.e. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mid%20off#:~:text=%3A%20a%20fielding%20position%20on%20the,player%20fielding%20in%20this%20position.) It's a bit ironic that someone would be closed for _not_ consulting Urban Dictionary.

Comment: _Mid off_ is, if I recall correctly, a cricket fielding position. There is also a _mid on_ and a _silly mid off_.

Comment: @KillingTime that’s seems likely to be correct. Suggest you convert the comment to a answer!

Answer (score 5):

The suffix "-off" is often used to generate a term that means a contest or competition, with the stem describing the quality or activity that the participants are being compared on. For instance a "cook-off" or "dance-off".

In this case, "mid" means in the middle (as in "mid-September"), and has a slang use to mean "mediocre".

The tweet is sarcastically saying that neither of the women is particularly exceptional, they're figuratively competing to see who can be more mediocre. The contained tweet seems to be one of the girls ("me" on the left) claiming to be better than the other ("you" on the right).